# Is there a way to concatenate with q objects?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-orm, qobject

I've been struggling with implementing this. I'm trying to build a dynamic queryset where the conditions will be based on user entry. A user can decide to search by first or last name or a combination of both. If searching by only last name the firstname query will not be added to the queryset. I currently have it working for a search with all the fields entered.

```
results = documents.objects.filter(
    Q(f_filer__filer_first_name__istartswith=request.GET.get('first_name', 
'')) & (f_filer__filer_last_name__istartswith=request.GET.get('last_name', 
'')) & 
Q(f_office__o_office_name__istartswith=request.GET.get('office_name', ''))
    & Q(f_doc_year__exact=request.GET.get('report_year', ''))
    & Q(f_report_id__exact=request.GET.get('filing_type', ''))       
    ).values('f_filer__filer_first_name',
          'f_filer__filer_last_name',
          'f_office__o_office_name',
          'f_date_received',
          'f_start_travel_date',
          'f_end_travel_date',
          'f_doc_year',
          'f_report__r_title')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just *concatenate* `filter` like this:

```
queryset = documents.objects.all()

first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
last_name = request.GET.get('last_name')

if first_name:
    queryset = queryset.filter(first_name=first_name)
if last_name:
    queryset = queryset.filter(last_name=lastname)
```

*I have shorten the filter arguments for simplifying the example*

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. Not as complicated as i thought. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can [join `Q` objects using `|`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q), which acts as an "or":

```
first_name = request.GET.get('first_name', '')
last_name = request.GET.get('last_name', '')
Q(
    f_filer__filer_first_name__istartswith=first_name,
    f_filer__filer_last_name__istartswith=last_name
) |
Q(f_filer__filer_first_name__istartswith=first_name) |
Q(f_filer__filer_last_name__istartswith=last_name)
```

If your application is search-heavy, it might be worth looking into setting up a proper search backend.

Do you use Postgres? If so, using Django's Postgres [Full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) would probably simplify things and help make the code more maintainable.

If you don't use Postgres, setting up a search backend with [django-haystack](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/en/master/tutorial.html) would give you similar benefits and allow users to construct Google-like queries using [AutoQuery](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.8.1/inputtypes.html#autoquery). For example, using `-` to exclude a term and quotes for an exact phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
from django.db.models import Q

query = Q()

query |= Q(field_one='xpto')   // use this for OR
query &= Q(field_two='foo')    // use this for AND
results = my_model.objects.filter(query)
```

Testing and working with python 3.10.12